# How to center a (background) image within a div?

Tags: html, css, image, background, center

Is it possible to center a background image in a div? I have tried just about everything - but no success:

```
<div id="doit">
  Lorem Ipsum ...
</div>

//CSS
#doit { background-image: url(images/pic.png); background-repeat: none; text-align: center; }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 312, accepted):

```
#doit {
    background: url(url) no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The specific CSS for centering is "background-position: center;"

Comment: @Green: See my answer for sprite background images.

Comment: If you want the entire div to be filled with the image and no extra space you should use `background-size: cover;`

If you want the entire image to show without any part of the image being  cut off or stretched you want to use `background-size: contain;`

Answer (score 88):

try    `background-position:center;`

EDIT: *since this question is getting lots of views, its worth adding some extra info:*

`text-align: center` will not work because the background image is not part of the document and  is therefore not part of the flow.

`background-position:center` is shorthand for `background-position: center center`; (`background-position: horizontal vertical`);

Comment: actually you just need `background-position:center;`

Comment: The selected answer cause my whole background to disappear for some reason (to be fair I'm doing some jquery stuff that may be causing it?), but this answer works. Upvote.

Answer (score 17):

For center or positioning the background image you should use `background-position` property .
The background-position property sets the starting position of a background image from `top` and `left` sides of the element .
The CSS Syntax is `background-position : xvalue yvalue;` .

"xvalue" and "yvalue" supported values are length units like `px` and percentage and direction names like left, right and etc .

The "xvalue" is the horizontal position of the background and starts from top of the element . It means if you use `50px` it will be "50px" away from top of the elements . And "yvalue" is the vertical position that has the same condition .

So if you use `background-position: center;` your background image will be centered .

But I always use this code :

```css
.yourclass {
  background: url(image.png) no-repeat center /cover;
 }
```

I know it is so confusing but it means :

```css
.yourclass {
  background-image: url(image.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And I know that too the `background-size` is a new property and in the compressed code what is `/cover` but these codes means `fill` background sizing and positioning in windows desktop background .

You can see more details about `background-position` in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) and `background-size` in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) .

Answer (score 16):

Use background-position:

```
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

Comment: useful if you need the image horizontally centered but on top vertically : background-position: 50% 0%;

Comment: 50% 0 is shorter then ;-) In CSS, you never need any unit when value is 0

Answer (score 7):

If your background image is a vertically aligned sprite sheet, you can horizontally center each sprite like this:

```
#doit {
    background-image: url('images/pic.png'); 
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: 50% [y position of sprite];
}
```

If your background image is a horizontally aligned sprite sheet, you can vertically center each sprite like this:

```
#doit {
    background-image: url('images/pic.png'); 
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: [x position of sprite] 50%;
}
```

If your sprite sheet is compact, or you are not trying to center your background image in one of the aforementioned scenarios, these solutions do not apply.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```css
#doit{
    background-image: url('images/pic.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
.network-connections-icon {
  background-image: url(url);
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` where `auto` makes it center horizontally within the div. Thank you!

Comment: Works with sprite sheet sprites too. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

This works for me for aligning the image to center of div.

```
.yourclass {
  background-image: url(image.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

```
<style>
   .WidgetBody
        {   
            background: #F0F0F0;
            background-image:url('images/mini-loader.gif');
            background-position: 50% 50%;            
            background-repeat:no-repeat;            
        }
</style>
```