# Placing div in the center of the page

Tags: html, css

i am starting  to learn css. I have this html and css. I am not able to center this image to center of the window. Please explain also how you got this output.

**Edited :
I want it to be center both vertically and horizonally**

Thank you.

```css
.myClass {
  background-image:url(http://www.funklix.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Clip-art-free-1.gif);
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center a (background) image within a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040232/how-to-center-a-background-image-within-a-div)

Comment: I am not centering background!! I am centering a div!

Comment: What is this -1 in left?

Comment: Your image is inside a div but the duplication about a div is also a duplicate. Search for it.

Comment: @David007 you have to accept answer bellow you have to click on tick on left side check my answer and click run code snippet

Comment: @Rob I too think that this question is a duplicate. **But its certainly not a duplicate of the question in your link.**

Comment: @ThePragmatick Doesn't matter. They're both duplicates.

Comment: This question is that every two days

Comment: I think it's actually funny, this question is on the forum so many times, yet so many ppl provide not working answers...

Comment: This kind of questions have flooded the whole css category on Stack Overflow

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are solutions for centering div!
[StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356401/3285730)

This is my preferred solution.

`HTML:`

```
<div class="container"><div class="container__inner"></div></div>
```

`CSS:`

```
.container{
  position:relative;
}
.container__inner{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Note that this solution only works if the container **has a fixed height**!
Read more about this here
   http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Comment: This is actually a nice way to do it, i use it all the time +1

Comment: this is the best way to center block +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to add margin to your class.

```
.myClass {
    background-image:url(http://www.funklix.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Clip-art-free-      1.gif);
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
```

This will add margin on each side of the element.

Comment: @Pinki you shouldn't downvote an answer to a question that was not specific. OP added in the edit about vertical and horizontal alignment after these answers were posted. It was not clear that he/she wanted both

Answer (score -1):

add `margin: auto`

```
.myClass {
  background-image:url(http://www.funklix.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Clip-art-free-1.gif);
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  margin: auto;
}
```